# finding Area using google maps and android?

Tags: android, google-maps, area

can we find area on earth using any web service powered by Google or something like this. like i can find elevation and directions using.

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/xml?" +
                "locations="+String.valueOf(latitude)+","
                +String.valueOf(longitude)
                +"&sensor=true";
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+one+","+two+"&daddr="+three+","+four+""));
                startActivity(intent);
```

so is there any help regarding finding area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below is good tutorial for starting with google maps in android and as you learn you can find google api's for places their elevation and places near a location

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: but I actually want to find Area.

Comment: by area do you mean city? you can map geolocation to cities areas and places